# Blank Page on Web Viewer Of BIRT report

Tags: birt

I am passing parameters to the .rptdesign file via a jsp page and generating the report. But after some days my reports started returning blank pages ....

[image]

Can anybody help me with probable causes of the problem ?

Comment: Hi Arindam :) Can you help on how to pass parameters to the .rptdesign file via the jsp page ?

Comment: Design the jsp page with usual drop down or text box and then submit the parameters to your struts action class, from the action class set the Parameters of the .rptdesign. The Birt Parameters must accept the default values as Javascript syntax which is something like ....
process_id=reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("process_id");
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("process_id",process_id);
this.value=process_id;

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed while working with BIRT is that sometimes the compatibility settings are needed. This is highly dependent on what version you are using (BIRT, Browser, OS, etc).

For example, I had the same issue recently where I was using BIRT4.5 and attempting to view a report in HTML. However the report is blank when opened normally. Only when viewing in compatibility mode with IE was I able to view the report.

For testing, you should attempt to open the report using different browsers (try setting your default browser to Google Chrome - I find it usually works with everything. Of course use your preferred if you have others). If it does not display in any viewer then it could be a problem with the report itself.